# Remote fonts in Firefox developer tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

The Firefox developer tools have section "fonts"

The screenshot I attach:

[image]

What does signature the "deleteded" mean next to the font name?

The screenshot I attach:

[image]

P.S. Screenshot made with the Russian version.  I assume that in the English version of the inscription "remove" or "delete"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple translation error. In the English version it reads "remote".

[image: Remote font label in Firefox DevTools]

The Russian translator probably misread it as "remove". I suggest you [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mozilla%20Localizations&component=ru%20/%20Russian), so it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (Remote font) this means that the font from a third-party source.
Namely downloaded from the Internet.

For example, on the BBC website font is installed "Arial".
In the Russian version is designated as a "systemic" (системный).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MJG6.png)